# String Pointers Used in If Statements Not Working

Tags: c, string, pointers, strtok

Used strtok to parse a string and now I am having difficulties with my IF statement.  Suspect that I am using the wrong case (value vs. address) but I have run out of ideas.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**I used a series of printf to confirm that strtok populated "hldType" correctly. Thanks again for any help.  I have been stuck on this for days.**

The abbreviated code is below.  The full code source is also included.

```
char *hldType;                        /* Parsing holding field */
static const char *REQTYPE = "0";     /* Comparison */

hldType = strtok(echoBuffer, ".");    /* Parse the string */
if (strcmp(hldType,REQTYPE)  == 0)    /* NOT WORKING */
    printf("REQTYPE myString: %s\n", REQTYPE);
```

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket() and bind() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_ntoa() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */
#include <time.h>       /* Display time */

#define ECHOMAX 255     /* Longest string to echo */

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);  /* External error handling function */
/* User Defined type */
typedef struct _ServerMessage{
    enum {New, Old, No_Message} messageType;    /* same size as an unsigned int */
    unsigned int SenderId;      /* unique client identifier */
    unsigned int RecipientId;       /* unique client identifier */
    char message[100];        /* text message */
} ServerMessage;       /* an unsigned int is 32 bits = 4 bytes */ 



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;                        /* Socket */
    struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr; /* Local address */
    struct sockaddr_in echoClntAddr; /* Client address */
    unsigned int cliAddrLen;         /* Length of incoming message */
    char echoBuffer[ECHOMAX];        /* Buffer for echo string */
    unsigned short echoServPort;     /* Server port */
    int recvMsgSize;                 /* Size of received message */
    char *hldType;                   /* Parsing holding field */
    char *hldSend;                   /* Parsing holding field */
    char *hldRecip;                  /* Parsing holding field */
    char *hldMsg;                    /* Parsing holding field */
    char tmpType[1];                    /* Type of action requested by client,   where     0 is Send and 1 is Received */
    static const char *REQTYPE = "0";



    /* Test Struct */
    /*ServerMessage ServerMessage_new = {No_Message, 1234,5678,"Hello Server World -     No   Message"}; */
    ServerMessage ServerMessage_new[100];
    /* printf("Message Type: %d\n", ServerMessage_new.messageType);
    printf("Message SenderID: %04d\n", ServerMessage_new.SenderId);
    printf("Message RecipentID: %04d\n", ServerMessage_new.RecipientId);
    printf("Message Content: %s\n", ServerMessage_new.message); */

    if (argc != 2)         /* Test for correct number of parameters */
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage:  %s <UDP SERVER PORT>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    echoServPort = atoi(argv[1]);  /* First arg:  local port */

    /* Create socket for sending/receiving datagrams */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
        DieWithError("socket() failed");

    /* Construct local address structure */
    memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr));   /* Zero out structure */
    echoServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                /* Internet address family */
    echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* Any incoming interface */
    echoServAddr.sin_port = htons(echoServPort);      /* Local port */

    /* Bind to the local address */
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0)
        DieWithError("bind() failed");

    for (;;) /* Run forever */
    {
        /* Set the size of the in-out parameter */
        cliAddrLen = sizeof(echoClntAddr);

        /* Block until receive message from a client */
        if ((recvMsgSize = recvfrom(sock, echoBuffer, ECHOMAX, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &echoClntAddr, &cliAddrLen)) < 0)
            DieWithError("recvfrom() failed");

        printf("Handling client %s\n", inet_ntoa(echoClntAddr.sin_addr));

        /* Parse string from client */
        printf("echoBuffer Content: %s\n", echoBuffer);
        hldType = strtok(echoBuffer, ".");
        hldSend = strtok(NULL, "."); 
        hldRecip = strtok(NULL, "."); 
        hldMsg = strtok(NULL, ".");
        printf("value of hldType: %s\n", hldType);  /* Validated that it prints "0" */
        /* Store message sent from client */

        time_t now;
        time(&now);
        printf("%s", ctime(&now));

        if (strcmp(hldType,REQTYPE)  == 0)    /* NOT WORKING */
            printf("REQTYPE myString: %s\n", REQTYPE);

        ServerMessage_new[0].messageType = atoi(hldType);
        printf("hldType Content: %d\n", ServerMessage_new[0].messageType);
        ServerMessage_new[0].SenderId = atoi(hldSend);
        printf("hldSend Content: %04d\n", ServerMessage_new[0].SenderId);
        ServerMessage_new[0].RecipientId = atoi(hldRecip);
        printf("hldRecip Content: %04d\n", ServerMessage_new[0].RecipientId);       
        strncpy(ServerMessage_new[0].message, hldMsg, 40);
        printf("hldMsg Content: %s\n", ServerMessage_new[0].message);

        /* Send received datagram back to the client */
        if (sendto(sock, echoBuffer, recvMsgSize, 0, 
             (struct sockaddr *) &echoClntAddr, sizeof(echoClntAddr)) != recvMsgSize)
            DieWithError("sendto() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
    }
    /* NOT REACHED */
}
```

Comment: Do a `printf("[%s] [%s]\n", s1, s2)` is see if the string are equals really..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    printf( "comparing [%s] to [%s]\n", hldType, REQTYPE);
    if (strcmp(hldType,REQTYPE)  == 0)    /* NOT WORKING */
        printf("REQTYPE myString: %s\n", REQTYPE);
```

You may find extra whitespace in one of your strings.  You can also print the return value from calling `strcmp()`.

If `hldType` and `REQTYPE` are both `"0"`, then `strcmp()` should be returning `0` (equal).

Comment: Good to hear that the IF condition should be returning 0.  I thought I was doing something wrong in comparing the string pointers (value vs. address, etc.). I will try your suggestion and post my results later today. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here are my results from printf statement above: comparing [String Data: 0] to [0]

Comment: So `hldType` is `"String Data: 0"` and not just `"0"`.  You need to strip the `"String Data: "` prefix if you're trying to compare the zeros.  Are you accidentally including the`"String Data: "` from the other end of your socket?

Comment: That has to be the answer.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think strtok isn't finding any parseable tokens. I mean, there's no "." in the input string. Check it.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  The item hldType is being populated by strtok.  I have confirmed this using a series of printf.